# Issue hibernate (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number)

Tags: java, hibernate

Not sure what can be causing this error...

I have a class named StudentUnit that can contain a  list of Units.

If I get only StudentUnit objects, the result comes ok, but if I try to get the Units (adding fetchType== eager), then I get java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

But note the fields I mapped on the Unit (unitCode, unitNm) are both Strings. I keep wondering if that could be a problem to have the unitCode as @id, or something related to that...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_UNITS")
@NamedQuery (name ="StudentUnit.findByCourseAttemptNo", 
query ="SELECT  su FROM StudentUnit su WHERE su.studentNo = :studentNo and su.courseNo = :courseNo and su.courseAttemptNo = :courseAttemptNo")
@FetchProfile(name = "studentUnit", fetchOverrides = { @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = StudentUnit.class, association = "units", mode = FetchMode.JOIN) })
public class StudentUnit{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NO")
    private Integer studentNo;


    @Column(name = "COURSE_NO")
    private Integer courseNo;


    @Column(name = "UNIT_CODE")
    private String unitCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "unitCode")//this one gives problems,which proves the issue is on Unit
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "unitCode"): this one is ok, once never tries to get the Unit
    private List<Unit> units;
}




@Entity
@Table(name="UNITS")
public class Unit {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UNIT_CODE")
    private String unitCode;

    @Column(name = "UNIT_NM")
    private String unitNm;

    @Column(name = "GRADE_CODE_NO")
    private Integer gradeCodeNo;


    @Column(name = "IMPLEMENTATION_DATE")
    private Date implementationDate;

     //getters/setters

}
```

Information from database:

```
  STUDENT_UNITS
    (
      STUDENT_NO              NUMBER(10),
      COURSE_NO               NUMBER(5),
      COURSE_ATTEMPT_NO       NUMBER(5),
      UNIT_CODE               VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
      ORIGINATING_DBKEY       NUMBER
    )

    UNITS
    (
      UNIT_CODE                 VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
      UNIT_STEM                 VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
      UNIT_ANTA_VERSION_NO      VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
      UNIT_NM                   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
      IMPLEMENTATION_DATE       DATE        
    )
```

More of the error log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:56)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:43)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy207.findStudentUnits(Unknown Source)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService.findStudentUnits(StudentUnitsService.java:21)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bfb0625f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6133a5f5.findStudentUnits(<generated>)
    servicePack.controller.StudentUnitsController.retrieveStudentUnits(StudentUnitsController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2228)
    org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:80)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1848)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:681)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1030)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:346)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    myPack.StudentUnitsSearchDaoImpl.findStudentUnits(StudentUnitsSearchDaoImpl.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy207.findStudentUnits(Unknown Source)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService.findStudentUnits(StudentUnitsService.java:21)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bfb0625f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6133a5f5.findStudentUnits(<generated>)
    servicePack.controller.StudentUnitsController.retrieveStudentUnits(StudentUnitsController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2228)
    org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65)
    org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:80)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1848)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:681)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1030)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:346)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    myPack.StudentUnitsSearchDaoImpl.findStudentUnits(StudentUnitsSearchDaoImpl.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    $Proxy207.findStudentUnits(Unknown Source)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService.findStudentUnits(StudentUnitsService.java:21)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bfb0625f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    servicePack.service.student.StudentUnitsService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6133a5f5.findStudentUnits(<generated>)
    servicePack.controller.StudentUnitsController.retrieveStudentUnits(StudentUnitsController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Thank you in advance,

Thais.

Comment: which OneToMany annotations are you using? the one for the persistance API or the Hibernate?

Comment: Hi Philipp, I am using persistence API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute:

```
    mappedBy = "unitCode"
```

is wrong: mappedBy should point to attribute of class StudentUnit, not String.
So just clear mappedBy = "unitCode" or try bidirectional mapping like this:

```
public class StudentUnit{

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "studentUnit")
    private List<Unit> units;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="UNITS")
public class Unit {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UNIT_CODE")
    private String unitCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_NO_ID")
    private StudentUnit studentUnit;

    @Column(name = "UNIT_NM")
    private String unitNm;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. 'unitCode' is an attribute in both classes.
I have other similar class doing the same thing...
Student is related to enrolments throght the attribute studentNo and it is working...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentNo")
 private List<Enrolment> enrolments;

Did I miss something?

Comment: But you cannot use UNIT_CODE as primary key in Unit class and as foreign key to link to StudentUnit - if this is primary key, so there will be no two Units pointing to one StudentUnit

Comment: I see guardian. thanks a lot for your inputs. Indeed, the difference is that the Enrolment had a key represented by studentNo, courseNo. 
In that case, I think I better map one more field as id for the units table... They are still defining this table, but I think that will be the approach, once today we detected repetition of unitCode on the unit table..

Comment: Show us your table definition - in Java your ids are Strings, maybe in database those ids are numbers?

Comment: Hi Gardian, now I fully understand your answer.
I mapped wrong. Instead of one student_unit having multiple units, it is a unit that may have many student_unit records. I fixed that by changing the StudentUnit.java and now it works. I still don't understand why it gives the number issue, but anyway, fixing the mapping sorted that out.
Sorry for my mistake, the project is starting and there are lots of definitions to be made. The database itself doesn't even have the key mappings, and so, at some point, I messed things up.